# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable Can't find error help please

Tags: python, typeerror

as part of a school project i was to find the mean and then the standard deviation of 3 sets of data. I correctly figured out the mean but when trying to do the step (x-average(x))^2 for standard deviation i seem to have made an error. This is my first time using python and programming. Please help!

```
import operator
dictionary = {
'male_temp': [96.3, 96.7, 96.9, 97, 97.1, 97.1, 97.1, 97.2, 97.3, 97.4, 97.4, 97.4, 97.4, 97.5, 97.5, 97.6, 97.6, 97.6, 97.7, 97.8, 97.8, 97.8, 97.8, 97.9, 97.9, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98.1, 98.1, 98.2, 98.2, 98.2, 98.2, 98.3, 98.3, 98.4, 98.4, 98.4, 98.4, 98.5, 98.5, 98.6, 98.6, 98.6, 98.6, 98.6, 98.6, 98.7, 98.7, 98.8, 98.8, 98.8, 98.9, 99, 99, 99, 99.1, 99.2, 99.3, 99.4, 99.5],
'female_temp': [96.4, 96.7, 96.8, 97.2, 97.2, 97.4, 97.6, 97.7, 97.7, 97.8, 97.8, 97.8, 97.9, 97.9, 97.9, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98.1, 98.2, 98.2, 98.2, 98.2, 98.2, 98.2, 98.3, 98.3, 98.3, 98.4, 98.4, 98.4, 98.4, 98.4, 98.5, 98.6, 98.6, 98.6, 98.6, 98.7, 98.7, 98.7, 98.7, 98.7, 98.7, 98.8, 98.8, 98.8, 98.8, 98.8, 98.8, 98.8, 98.9, 99, 99, 99.1, 99.1, 99.2, 99.2, 99.3, 99.4, 99.9, 100, 100.8],
'female_beats': [69, 62, 75, 66, 68, 57, 61, 84, 61, 77, 62, 71, 68, 69, 79, 76, 87, 78, 73, 89, 81, 73, 64, 65, 73, 69, 57, 79, 78, 80, 79, 81, 73, 74, 84, 83, 92, 85, 86, 77, 72, 79, 59, 64, 65, 82, 64, 70, 83, 89, 69, 73, 84, 76, 79, 81, 80, 74, 77, 79, 78, 77]}

averages = {}
for user_info, v in dictionary.items():
    average = sum(v)*1.0/len(v)
    averages[user_info] = average
sorted_averages = sorted(averages.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
for user_name, average in sorted_averages:
    print("{} mean {}".format(user_name, average))

standard_deviation = {}
total_of = 0
for user_info, v in dictionary.items():
    total_of += (v-average[v])**2
    total_divided = total_of*1.0/len(v)
    standard_dev = tatal_divided**0.5
    standard_dev[user_info] = standard_dev
sorted_standard_dev = sorted(standard_dev.items(),        key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
for user_name, standard_dev in sorted_standard_dev:
    print("{} Standard Deviation {}".format(user_name, standard_dev))
```

and the error that i'm getting is

```
....,line 18, in <module> total_of += (v - average[v])**2
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You want to use `averages[v]`, you are missing an `s`.

Comment: You can't find the error? The error message tells you exactly where the problem is...

Comment: @cricket_007: only if you realise that the `object[..]` syntax is called subscription.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant `averages[v]` instead of `average[v]`. average is a `float` and floats don't support indexing, which is why you get the error `object is not subscriptable`

Comment: hi, thanks for the fast reply! Just tried that out and got a different error 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'list''

Comment: @EmiliaFoster: you are trying to use a list object as a key in a dictionary, or as a value in a set somewhere.

Comment: @EmiliaFoster: `v` is a list, you can't use that as a key. Did you mean to use the `user_info` variable as a key instead perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

There's a chance that your issue stems from you average[v] not being 'subscriptable' which mean something along the lines of this object can't be indexed.